# Why does a label's text alignment and color revert to default values after reloadData?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uilabel

I am using the basic (default) style for my storyboard tableView cell.  Within the storyboard, I've set the built-in label's `textAlignment` to center, and `textColor` to grey.

The first time the cell is shown, the label's text alignment and color match the storyboard values:
[image: Label initially appears with storyboard values]

When the tableView data is reloaded (due to a content size change), the text alignment and color may revert to default (left text alignment, black text color) values.
[image: Label properties revert to default values after reloadData]

Is this an iOS 8 issue?  I don't recall needing to set `textAlignment` or `textColor` in code with iOS 7.  If it matters, the cells are using self-sizing.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    . . .
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
}

- (void)contentSizeChanged:(NSNotification *)__unused notification {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"No Results" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = ([indexPath row] == 2) ? @"No Results" : @"";
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];

    // Must set alignment/color, or the properties for a built-in (basic) cell style
    // may revert to default values when the tableView data is reloaded.

    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8f alpha:1.0f];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This apparently is a recurring issue with `UILabel`.

Formatting properties set in the storyboard are lost when the label's text changes.  The workaround is to set the label's `textAlignment` and `textColor` in code *after* setting its `text`.

This shows up in iOS 7 beta, was fixed, and apparently has resurfaced in iOS 8.

There's [an OpenRadar mention](http://www.openradar.me/14125345) of this problem, along with [a thread on Apple's Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/824937#824937). (Developer Program membership required.)

I'll be filing a bug report to track the status of this issue.